# Динамические массивы в stl

Tags: c++, массивы, матрицы, stl

Хочу создать квадратную матрицу с помощью stl и чтобы пользователь сам заполнял массив. 
Пока код такой:

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS 
#include <iostream> 
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <conio.h> 
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main () {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Rus");
    int e;
    cin >> e;
    vector<vector<int> > e;
    e.push_back(vector<int>());

    for (int i = 0; i < e.size(); i++) {
        cout << e[i] << " ";
    }
    cout << endl;
    _getch();
return 0;
}
```

Пишет ошибки над е "выражение должно иметь тип класса" и где е[i] - выражение должно иметь тип указателя на объект.

Были разные ошибки, брала часть решений c этого сайта хд Но так и до конца не поняла как создать двумерный массив, чтобы потом запихнуть туда цикл на проверку количества введенных строк и столбцов.

Было бы классно еще где можно прочитать более подробную информацию об этой библиотеке, тк там еще есть продолжения задания хд

Answer (score 1):

Имена переменных в программе должны быть разными. Зачем Вы пишите:

```
int e;
...
vector<vector<int>> e;
```

Для начала измените названия переменных, можно даже на более звучащие имена.

Строкой `e.push_back(vector<int>());` Вы добавляете пустую строку в вашу "матрицу", вместо того, чтобы инициализировать её. Попробуйте для инициализации добавить несколько строк и отдельно заполнить каждый элемент, например так:

```
vector<vector<int>> v(rowCount);  // создадим сразу rowCount строк


for (int i = 0; i < v.size(); i++)         // перебираем строки
{
    v[i].resize(colCount);                 // расширяем i-ую строку до размера colCount

    for (int j = 0; j < v[i].size(); j++)  // перебираем элементы i-той строки
    {
        cin >> v[i][j];                    // заполняем элемент i-той строки j-ого столбца
    }
}
```

Для вывода нельзя использовать:

```
cout << v[i];
```

В этом случае Вы пытаетесь вывести весь вектор-строку, в то время как ваша программа не умеет этого делать. Следовательно, Вам нужно перебрать каждый элемент. Вывод на экран аналогичен вводу. Используйте вложенные циклы, как в примере с вводом.

По поводу "почитать" пару полезных ссылок:

1. [cplusplus.com/vector](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/vector/vector/?kw=vector)
2. [en.cppreference.com/container/vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)

Comment: По порядку: 1) Я написала в cin е, потому что у меня выскакивала ошибка про не перегрузку унарных операторов и на этом сайте предложили этот вариант исправления. Тогда наверно в тех двух строчках нет смысла. 2) vector<vector<int>> v(rowCount) - правильно я понимаю, что вы предлагаете задать количество самому вместо rowCount? 3) e.push_back(vector<int>()); - тоже предлагался как вариант, чтобы пользователь сам мог вводить

Comment: я посмотрела программу. Получается когда мы вводим rowcount и colcount, то они перемножаются? Я несколько раз пробовала и по количеству элементов выходит именно так. Хотя вроде написано, что он должен расширять или уменьшать уже созданный контейнер

Comment: 1) не совсем понял, что Вы имели ввиду. 2) здесь я имел ввиду, что в скобках можно указать необходимое количество, вплоть до ввода значения `cin >> rowCount;`, которое затем можно использовать для инициализации вектора. 3) В строчке `e.push_back(vector<int>());` Вы создаете **одну** строку в матрице. Используя в скобках `rowCount` Вы делаете аналогичные действия `rowCount` раз создавая набор строк.

Comment: @RedRose, логически да, они перемножаются. Речь же шла про квадратную матрицу? В квадратной (ну, будем честными, в прямоугольной) матрице `кол-во_элементов = кол-во_строк * кол-во_столбцов`. А по поводу "**... хотя вроде написано, что он должен расширять или уменьшать уже созданный контейнер**", все зависит, как Вы будете его использовать. Сейчас Вы его только лишь инициализируете. Если Вы захотите его расширить, пожалуйста, все в Ваших руках. Пару строк кода, и матрица расширится.

Comment: @RedRose, кстати добавил парочку полезных ссылок, которыми сам время от времени пользуюсь

Comment: 1) я имела в виду, что написала е в сине и векторе, потому что выскакивала ошибка и предлагали такой вариант исправления.2)а можно, чтобы сам пользователь решил какого размера матрица? и может задать количество строк и столбцов одним действием, дабы исключить глупость юзера и не делать проверку. Нужна мне квадратная, потому что дальше задание с диагональю, поэтому так заморачиваюсь хд Спасибо за ссылки!

Comment: @RedRose, конечно можно. Как я уже сказал, всё в Ваших руках :) Задайте вместо `rowCount` и `colCount` одно значение, например `N`, которое и будет размерностью